# Graph Theory problem involving cut-vertex.

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a graph without any articulation vertices such that each vertex has degree at least $3$. Prove that $G$ contains a subgraph that can be contracted to a $K_4$.

**My Attempt:** Begin with the cycle of the largest length $p$. Then since every vertex has degree at least $3$, this implies that $p\geq 4.$ Now I need to show that $p=4$, but I am unable to do so. Any hints/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Note: This is problem $30,$ Pg: $501$, Chapter: $12.7$ from the book Introductory Combinatorics by Richard A. Brualdi.

Comment: Someone, please solve this problem! I can't even put a Bounty right now..